# How to read and interpret the following mathematical notation? $\Gamma_{su} = \frac{P_sG_{su}}{\sum_{i\in S\{\backslash s\}}P_iG_{iu}+P_{AWGN}}$

Tags: calculus, probability, summation, ratio

I came across the following expression in a research paper:

$$\Gamma_{su} = \frac{P_sG_{su}}{\sum_{i\in S\{\backslash s\}}P_iG_{iu}+P_{AWGN}}$$

My query is how to read that small $s$ in denominator which has left slash with it.

Any help in this regard will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Perhaps a link or mention of the paper where you found this expression would be helpful.

Comment: Thank you sir for your reply....."User Association for Backhaul Load Balancing with
Quality of Service Provisioning for Heterogeneous
Networks" This is the title of the paper and its equation 2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Equation 2 in the research paper](https://repository.uwl.ac.uk/id/eprint/6103/1/Loo_etal_IEEE_CL_User_association_for_backhaul_load_balancing_with_quality_of_service_provisioning_for_heterogeneous_networks.pdf) is

$$\Gamma_{su} = \frac{P_sG_{su}}{\sum_{i\in S\backslash\{ s\}}P_iG_{iu}+P_{AWGN}}$$

The notation $S\backslash\{ s\}$ usually means [set difference](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/SetDifference.html) which is $S - \{s\}$ in this case where $\{s\}$ is the set containing a single element $s$. Hence, the denominator of the expression has the sum of $P_iG_{iu}$ for all $i \in S$ apart from $s$.